# Rewrite url using .htaccess in php not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want rewrite below url

http://www.example.com/page.php?n=About%2BUs&id=F534Z531G538

to

http://www.example.com/about-us

using .htaccess file.
i have tried below code in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^page.php?n=About%2BUs&id=F534Z531G538(.*)$ http://www.example.com/about-us$1 [r=301,nc]
```

but this is not working and also id is randomly generate.

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 RewriteRule ^about-us/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1
```

for http://www.example.com/about-us/f14dfa

for http://www.example.com/about-us

```
 RewriteRule ^about-us$ page.php
```

Comment: i have tried both and it is working but not properly. this code load only page but css is not working.

Comment: check css link properly.

Comment: css link is not found. css link changed to about-us/css/style.css.

Comment: also i have a another problem because of random id generation.

Comment: define root path and make it like <?php echo $root_url;?>/css/style.css     $root_url=domain.com

Comment: i changed it..but what about random id if i write url like http://www.example.com/about-us/f14dfa this then it load page but not its content..

Comment: actually this random id is a encoding of some unique id of about-us page.every time this unique id is encoded and generate random number.

Comment: @RubbySmith add this to the head section of your page **<base href="/">** it corrects the header uri base for css,js and other relative links.